# Generate strings using data in a data.frame, using the colnames, and combining the data in different ways based on the value

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe that I would like to use to build an sql query.

Here is a segment of my data:

```
Data <- structure(list(inclass = c("01", "99", "99"), childage = c("0", 
"2", "4"), high_edu = c("00", "00", "14"), ref_race = c("1", 
"1", "1")), .Names = c("inclass", "childage", "high_edu", "ref_race"
), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L), class = "data.frame")
```

I need to create different kinds of phrases based on all the rows of data, where if the value is '99' it behaves differently.

**Phrase1:** if the value is '99' it should say "'99' as columnname" otherwise it should just use the columnname.

so for the 2nd row it would look like:

```
'99' as inclass, childage, high_edu, ref_race
```

**Phrase2:** if it's not '99' combine the columnname with the value.

so for the 2nd row it would look like:

```
childage = '2', high_edu = '00', ref_race = '1'
```

**Phrase3:** paste the columnnames where the value isn't '99'

```
childage, high_edu, ref_race
```

I am having a hard time figuring out how to combine the data based on whether the value is/isn't '99'

**EDIT**

I think my question might have been a bit confusing.
I am trying to get these three phrases for each row. 
Here is data that will probably make it clearer what I am trying to do.

```
    structure(list(inclass = c("01", "99", "99", "1", "2"), childage = c("0", 
"99", "4", "6", "3"), high_edu = c("00", "99", "14", "99", "99"
), ref_race = c("1", "1", "1", "99", "4"), phrase1 = c("inclass, childage, high_edu, ref_race", 
"'99' as inclass, '99' as childage, '99' as high_edu, ref_race", 
"'99' as inclass, childage, as high_edu, ref_race", "inclass, childage, '99' as high_edu, '99' as ref_race", 
"inclass, childage, '99' as high_edu, ref_race"), phrase2 = c("inclass = '01', childage = '0', high_edu = '00', ref_race = '1'", 
"ref_race = '1'", "childage = '4', high_edu = '14', ref_race = '1'", 
"inclass = '1', childage = '6'", "inclass = '2', childage = '3', ref_race = '4'"
), phrase3 = c("inclass, childage, high_edu, ref_race", "ref_race", 
"childage, high_edu, ref_race", "inclass, childage", "inclass, childage, ref_race"
)), .Names = c("inclass", "childage", "high_edu", "ref_race", 
"phrase1", "phrase2", "phrase3"), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Are these phrases supposed to be different events?  The condition in Phrase2 and Phrase3 are the same so this cannot be just one piece of code.

Comment: @cdeterman they don't have to be one event. They are going to be different parts of an sql statement. They can be generated separately, and then combined.

Comment: Is it only if the first column contains "99" or any column?

Comment: @cdeterman any column can contain a '99'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this should solve your problem.  It may not be the most elegant but I think it is at least straightforward.  You want to look in to functions like `any` and get familiar with `paste` when you want specific output like that.  Essentially, all I am doing is getting the column names where the values are either '99' or not.  Then it is just a matter of utilizing `paste` properly.

```
for(i in seq(nrow(Data))){
    idx <- which(Data[i,1:4] == "99")
    idxn <- which(Data[i,1:4] != "99")
    cols99 <- colnames(Data)[idx]
    colsn99 <- colnames(Data)[idxn]
    if(any(idx)){
        nn <- paste("'99' as", colnames(Data)[idx])
        Data[i,"phrase1"] <-
            paste(
                c(nn, colsn99), 
                collapse=", ")            
    }else{
        Data[i,"phrase1"] <-
            paste(
                colsn99, 
                collapse=", ")
    }

    if(any(idxn)){
        Data[i, "phrase2"] <- 
            paste(
                paste(
                    colsn99, 
                    paste("'", Data[i,idxn],"'", sep=""), 
                    sep="="), 
                collapse=", ")
        Data[i, "phrase3"] <- paste(colsn99, collapse=", ")

    }
}
```

Comment: I guess my question wasn't clear that I need these 3 phrases for each row. I edited my question with more information. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Elks, that makes more sense now, please see my edit.